# Why don't the SHA's match?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pipe, hashsum

I am trying to write a script and it uses the SHA of a date but I am getting two different results and for the life of me can't figure out why.

```
echo -n 03112016 | cut -d'.' -f4 | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f 1
482c00f7db8419d9f9a151d54de301d73c8f688b2e3e91c485f369596543612e

date "+%m%d%Y" | tr -d '\n' | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f 1
d373ab72ec7d92ee06ebba4748f78829cd62ce68f1ac600ae1767a272869b664
```

I know it has to be something stupid on my end but I really appreciate any help.

Comment: There's a newline character that makes the difference there... What's the `echo .... | cut -d'.' -f4` supposed to mean ? Either use `printf %s 03112016  | sha256sum` or remove the `tr` from your second command...

Comment: Thank you sir, as for your question concerning cut that's the hard coded date the command actually pulls that date from a file name so it grabs the string with cut.

Comment: Well, `cut` will always add a newline (even if it doesn't _cut_ anything) just so you know...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, thats the part I was over looking. I knew it was something stupid on my part... Sigh it's been a long week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell utilities that are designed to operate on text (such as `cat`, `cut`, `sort`, `tail`, etc.) require their input to be text files. A text file, in Unix terms:

- consists only of valid characters in the ambient locale (`LC_CTYPE` locale setting), other than the null byte;
- consists of a sequence of lines, each of which is terminated by a newline character (`\n`, a.k.a. line feed).

That second point implies that any non-empty file ends with a newline character.

What happens if the input is not a text file depends on the utility. Old Unix systems tended to ignore text on a line after a null byte, and to ignore all or part of the last incomplete line (text after the last newline character). GNU versions always treat null bytes as an ordinary character and mostly pass through invalid byte sequences. GNU versions always process the whole input even if the final newline is missing, but they differ in whether they add a trailing newline in their output. For example, GNU `cat` always passes its input through unchanged, but many others, including `cut`, always print a newline at the end of each output line including the last one.

So when you produce the reference input, you need to suppress the trailing newline at the last minute.

```
echo 03112016 | cut -d'.' -f4 | tr -d '\n' | sha256sum
```

or just

```
echo -n 03112016 | sha256sum
```